# React Tailwindcss- background color and text are the same size

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

The backgound color is too close to the text. I have no idea why it is like that

I have searched the documents for help but cant seem to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use padding from tailwind css for text "p-5"

Comment: Thank you that worked fine. Can I ask another question?

Comment: ya sure you can ask

Comment: Any change I made in tailwindcss style, doesn't show until I close  and rerun npm start

Comment: you can start the application in watch mode or use nodemon npm package